Error when running code on Dart & Flutter
Error at the first launch of the base application :
 PS C:\\Users\\neket\\OneDrive\\Документы\\flutter\\flutter_application_1\> flutter run Launching lib\\main.dart on sdk gphone16k x86 64 in debug mode...  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.  \* Where: 

Build file 
'C:\\Users\\neket\\OneDrive\\���������\\flutter\\flutter_application_1\\android\\app\\build.gradle' line: 2  \* What went wrong: An exception occurred applying plugin request \[id: 'com.android.application'\] \> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.

    \> Your project path contains non-ASCII characters. This will most likely cause the build to fail on Windows. Please move your project to a different directory. See http://b.android.com/95744 for details. This warning can be disabled by adding the line 'android.overridePathCheck=true' to gradle.properties file in the project directory.  \* Try: \> Run with
    --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. \> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

 \> Run with --scan to get full insights.  \* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org  BUILD FAILED in 843ms Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                        1 544ms Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Tried rebuilding - didn't help

It does not work because the your folder name contains non-ASCII characters. Try to run it by creating a projects folder under the C:\Users\neket path and moving it under that folder. This way you can run it.

It does not work because the your folder name contains ASCII characters. Almost every folder name contains ASCII characters. You meant non-ASCII?

@MarcinOrlowski Yes, I got it mixed up. Thank you for pointing that out!
